# How do I import data from text file into an Excel sheet with blank rows acting as separators?

Tags: excel

I'm trying to import from a text file that is all in two columns. The data is in blocks that all relate to each other but may be of a different number of rows. For example, the first block of data is 12 rows long and then there's a blank row. The second set of data starts after that and goes on for 15 rows and then there's another blank row before the next data set. And so on. What I want to do is to import each data set to its own row but I can't seem to find a way to do it. I've googled it but trying to put what I wish to do into a google search isn't really helping. I want it split over multiple columns. Any ideas?

Comment: Please share sample data from the text file and desired results in excel. Sample data/desired results are worth 1000 words of explanation. Where I'm really struggling to understand is "Import each data set to its own row". Desired results would help clear that up. Likely you will need some VBA since your input data is non-standard and the way you want it imported is non-standard.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I broke it down into three stages. It would work if there is only a single blank row between the data sets in column A.

- In cell `B3`

  ```
  =IF(A3<>"",IF(B2<>"",B2,B1+1),"")
  ```
- In cell `C3`

  ```
  =IFERROR(ADDRESS(ROW($A3),$B3+3),"")
  ```
- In cell `D3`

  ```
  =IF(CELL("address",D3)=$C3,$A3,"")
  ```